# Error sending multiple input to keras network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to build a network that takes in 3 input (Image) and 1 output bounding box (x0, y0, x1, y1). The network consists of 3 VGG16 networks and concatenate into one layer and join with 4 fully connected layers.  But when I try to send input to the network, it produces the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that 
    you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected 
    to see 3 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2 arrays:
```

But I am sending the correct number of input to the network. Need advice here! Thanks in advace.

Code: Build Network

```
vgg_conv_1 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
vgg_conv_2 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
vgg_conv_3 = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

merged_layer = Concatenate(axis = 3)([vgg_conv_1.output, vgg_conv_2.output, vgg_conv_3.output])
merged_layer = Flatten()(merged_layer)
merged_layer = Dense(units = 1024, activation = "relu")(merged_layer)
merged_layer = Dense(units = 1024, activation = "relu")(merged_layer)
merged_layer = Dense(units = 1024, activation = "relu")(merged_layer)
merged_layer = BatchNormalization()(merged_layer)
merged_layer = Dropout(0.25)(merged_layer)
merged_layer = Dense(units = 4, activation = "sigmoid")(merged_layer)

newModel = Model([vgg_conv_1.input, vgg_conv_2.input, vgg_conv_3.input], merged_layer)

newModel.compile(optimizer = "sgd", loss = l2loss, metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

Code: Load Data (Both Training and validation set), labels = (x0, y0, x1, y1)

```
training_set_1 = []
training_set_2 = []
training_set_3 = []
train_labels = []

with open("train.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        lines = line.rstrip("\n")
        line_split = lines.split(",")
        try:
            training_1 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(line_split[0], target_size = (224, 224))
            x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(training_1)
            x = preprocess(x)
            training_set_1.append(x)

            training_2 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(line_split[1], target_size = (224, 224))
            x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(training_2)
            x = preprocess(x)
            training_set_2.append(x)

            training_3 = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(line_split[2], target_size = (224, 224))
            x = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(training_3)
            x = preprocess(x)
            training_set_3.append(x)

            train_labels.append(np.array([line_split[3],line_split[4],
                  line_split[5],line_split[6] ]))
        except:
            pass
```

Code: Training

```
traingen = ImageDataGenerator(fill_mode="constant")
valgen = ImageDataGenerator(fill_mode="constant")

newModel.fit_generator( traingen.flow(x = [ np.array(training_set_1),np.array(training_set_2), np.array(training_set_3) ], 
    y = np.array(train_labels), batch_size = 16),
    steps_per_epoch = 8000,
    epochs = 10,
    validation_data = valgen.flow(x = [ np.array(test_set_1), np.array(test_set_2), np.array(test_set_3) ], y = np.array(test_labels)),
    validation_steps = 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have taken a look at the documentation of the `ImageDataGenerator` and especially its `flow(...)` method. It says

> x: Input data. Numpy array of rank 4 or a tuple. If tuple, the first
>   element should contain the images and the second element another numpy
>   array or a list of numpy arrays that gets passed to the output without
>   any modifications.

This means, that the `x` argument can only be a list/tuple of `2` items, not `3`. If you want to pass `3` items, you have to do it like this:

```
traingen.flow(
    x=(np.array(training_set_1), [np.array(training_set_2), np.array(training_set_3)]), 
    y=...   
 ...
)
```